# Change color of a most controls (ie TPanel) in a Firemonkey app in Delphi (XE2 Update4 and XE3 only)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

NOTE: This question is about a behaviour in delphi XE2 update 4, and delphi XE3, and the style system was changed in XE4, so this question does not apply to Delphi versions XE4 and up.

Many controls like TPanel and so on, do not support a simple way to change color of any element without going into the "Styles" feature.

The way I think it's supposed to work is:

1. Create a form.
2. Put a StyleBook on the form.
3. Change or create a style.
4. Apply a style to the control.
5. Control changes color.

Let's leave aside the fact that something that should be easy (as it was in the VCL) is now convoluted by Styles. What are the actual working steps for Delphi XE2 (Firemonkey Update4) to make a TPanel blue instead of gray (its defaults)?

Actual results: When I try the above, I get a freeze-up lasting about 30 seconds, memory usage exceeding 1 gb of memory for bds.exe, and then I get a crash.Sometimes I get "AQReporter.dll needs to close", and sometimes other errors from other IDE plugins, finally an "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows has stopped working" error.

Comment: This might be pertinent: http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/how-to-have-a-blue-fmx-tpanel/

Comment: Very nice! I think that a library of Helper functions to set the colors of firemonkey controls, and so on, would be nice to write, to wrap all that hackery up in something nice.

Comment: Random downvoter; Please comment why you think this question sucks.

Comment: Setting styling info separate from the form designer is the same thing as not peppering your code with constants. It may take more work to set up but is much more flexible in the long run. In fact, I wish they'd taken the idea further with control positions and sizes controlled from the style.

Comment: Understandable - however many people control the appearance of application elements with special coloration - red for errors, sometimes selection colors etc.  Even when such coloration is applied from a "style sheet design", it may be necessary to modify coloration at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that among other bugs, sometimes the TForm.StyleBook property does not automatically get assigned. If you make sure it is assigned, then the above steps work.

Quick steps:

1. Create form.
2. Drop style book on form, and assign Form.StyleBook = StyleBook1
3. Right click on control you wish to modify style on, click Edit Custom Style.
4. Go to object inspector and modify Fill property to change background color of panel, for instance.
5. Apply and close. (May have to click two, three or four times due to window focus bugs)

[image]

Note: This workaround is not useful in Delphi XE4 and up as the feature "Custom style setting" was removed from Mobile application FMX.

Comment: Not really sure It's a bug, but it's a 'feature' which has caught me a few times. you can have multiple StyleBooks on a form and change which one is assigned to the form's Stylebook property. You can also assign a form's StyleBook property to a stylebook on another form. It would be a convenient default to have the first StyleBook created on a form set the forms StyleBook property to itself, though.

Comment: BTW if you *don't* create a stylebook, but right click -> Edit Custom Style one will be created automatically and assigned to the form.

Comment: Btw, there IS no "Edit custom style" on Firemonkey mobile apps now. http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115376

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Warrens answer, for Delphi versions newer than the ones he was using, XE4 and up, to modify the style of the panel at runtime you need to change the style in the style book and then re-assign the style to the panel.  Specifically:

```
var
  R: TFMXObject;
begin
  R := StyleBook1.Style.FindStyleResource('Panel1Style1');
  if R is TRectangle then
    TRectangle(R).Fill.Color := claRed;

  Panel1.StyleLookup := 'Panel1Style1';
end;
```

It's important to remember that for this to work you must have created a custom style in a style book  (as per Warren's answer).  In this example it is called 'Panel1Style1' but you could replace this name with something totally different.

Comment: What version of Delphi is this in?

Comment: I've tested this in XE5, Seattle & Tokyo.

Comment: Ok. I think this works differently than in my original question. I think they changed stuff in XE4, so your answer would probably work for anything XE4 and up.